# Were the Apollo lunar ALSEP transmitter signals ever analyzed or used after the experiments were shut down?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, apollo-program, history

[image]

This [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26506/12102) to the question *Why were the “perfectly functioning” seismometers placed by Apollo 12, 14, 15 and 16 astronauts all shut off in 1977?* links to a [NASA News Release No: 77-47](https://repository.hou.usra.edu/bitstream/handle/20.500.11753/892/VF5.pdf) dated September 12, 1977. It says:

> **Lunar Science Stations to Cease Functioning September 30**
>
> On September 30, against the backdrop of a waning moon, Science instruments on the lunar surface will be turned off and the ALSEP (Apollo Lunar Surface Experiments Package) control center at NASA’s Johnson Space Center, Houston, will be dismantled.
>
> The Apollo lunar science stations will be shut down because of dwindling power reserves at the stations and budgetary limitations here on Earth.

**However!** starting at the bottom of page 4, it seems NASA scientists found a way to try to squeeze more science out of the situation; given lemons, *they tried to make some Lunar Lemonade*.

> Even though the experiments will be terminated, **the transmitters will continue to serve Earth as a reference point in astronomy**. The Jet Propulsion Laboratory will continue to **use the signals from the ALSEP transmitters** to assist in the Lab's deep space work including geodetic and astrometric studies and spacecraft navigation. Also, the motion of the lunar orbit will be accurately monitored against a background of extra-galactic stars to test gravitational theories.

**Question:** Were any experiments of this kind ever carried out? Were signals from any of the transmitters ever at least received, or perhaps analyzed? Was any science extracted or possibly published from these measurements?

Comment: In this NASA [page](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/experimentDisplay.do?id=1971-063C-12) there is a short note about such an experiment. " Because of an intermittent signal and poor coverage, only an insignificant amount of data resulted from this experiment."

Comment: Some more links about ALSEP VLBI measurements: [1](https://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00640904), [2](https://earth-planets-space.springeropen.com/articles/10.5047/eps.2010.08.005), [3](https://lunar.gsfc.nasa.gov/library/02b-Lunar_Crd_Sys-Archinal.pdf), [4](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19780036273&hterms=alsep), [5](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/lsc1976/pdf/1284.pdf), [6](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1977Moon...17..133S), [7](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/23904836_Precision_selenodesy_and_lunar_libration_through_VLBI_observations_of_ALSEPs).

Comment: Some of the links to papers I found are paywalled, I found no information about measurment results after 1977 in free papers.

Comment: @Uwe The experiment mentioned in your first comment linking [here](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/experimentDisplay.do?id=1971-063C-12) used signals from the *Apollo 15 spacecraft in lunar orbit* as well, and so is not really related.

Comment: The tag "Mission Name: Apollo 15 Lunar Module /ALSEP" is somewhat misleading. There is no relation to ALSEP for the spacecraft in orbit.

Comment: @Uwe do you think you have enough here for an answer? It looks like you've done a lot of research!

Comment: @Uwe you have a lot of research here, do you think you might have enough to write at least a short answer?