# With and without refilling at LEO, how much more than the landers weight of the Venera 9 mission could a Starship deliver near a pole of Venus?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, spacex-starship, venus, entry-descent-landing, venera

[Venera 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venera_9) was a Soviet space mission to Venus that consisted of an orbiter and lander with a launch mass of **4936 kg** and with an entry mass of **1560 kg.** It was the first spacecraft to return an image from the **surface** of another planet.

[image: Venus surface]
(Click on the image for a closer view.)

The launch rocket was the [Proton-K/D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton-K) that was part of the program to land Soviet cosmonauts on the Moon, with 3 stages each having specific impulses varying from **316 to 327 sec.**
Could Starship with its [Raptor engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Raptor) with specific impulses at sea level of **330 sec.** accomplish such a mission to Venus with a (much) heavier lander to prolong the lifetime of its instruments on the surface ?
And could landing near a pole be more challenging because the descent would have to start at one pole (since its axis is perpendicular to the spacecrafts trajectory plane), while the spacecraft  would still have to orbit half the planet to finally land at the other one ?

Comment: From the Wikipedia article: "The entry sphere weighed 1,560 kg (3,440 lb) and the surface payload was 660 kg (1,455 lb)." It shed the entry sphere much like how M2020 & MSL shed the aeroshell

Comment: ...if you're looking for polar ice on Venus, you're going to be disappointed.

Comment: @Cornelis I'm very confident that's the whole lander, but no proof.

Comment: Coming in from an interplanetary trajectory, with a Venusian atmosphere to aerobrake in, if you have any ability to do fine adjustments en-route, the delta-v requirements are negligible to aim for any landing zone on the side of the planet facing  you on arrival.

Comment: @notovny is that for aerobraking into orbit?

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 Even if you don't aerobrake, interplanetary distances are large, and planets are _tiny_ in comparison. If you want to pick a point on the planet to smack into (or land propulsively, if you've got the thrust and fuel for it), if you have the control and time, the cost to hit any point on the facing surface is effectively the same.

Comment: @notovny it is easy to *aim* for a particular point (i.e., B-plane targeting) fuel wise; however, the resulting entry trajectories are enormously different and require entirely different vehicle/mission designs. Also note that with lower arrival energies (ideal for atmospheric entry) the hyperbolic trajectory will (for Venus) pull you to the other side of the planet before entry.

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 I'm not seeing anything of particular significance that makes a polar entry different from an equatorial one. And indeed, the Pioneer Venus Multiprobe targeted multiple widely separated areas with identical sub-probes launched from a single spacecraft.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff it's not the inclination/latitude, it's the [hyperbolic impact parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_trajectory#Impact_parameter_and_the_distance_of_closest_approach) (i.e., distance from B-plane origin) that determines the entry flight path angle (critical parameter, see [page 5](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20130001711)).

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff The Pioneer probes all had [similar entry flight path angles](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20070022789) considering the ["regimes of sensitivity" from page 5 figure](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20130001711). It's a non-linear sensitivity, sure, but dramatically different environments nonetheless are possible.

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 ...which illustrates that the hyperbolic impact parameter isn't of particular relevance here.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I'm puzzled how you've come to this conclusion, I come to *the exact opposite conclusion* after reading that chart.

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 I'm puzzled how you can stick with a conclusion in the face of a clear and unambiguous counterexample. The facts are, given Venus' low axial tilt and inclination, the set of orbits with a given impact parameter will cover nearly the entire range (if not actually the entire range) of latitudes with near-identical entry trajectories and reentry requirements.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff it seems there's been a misunderstanding, I *mostly* agree with your last statement. My original gripe was with Notovny's statement "hit any point on the facing surface" (**interpreted as any B.R & B.T, or x & y, point in the B-plane**) which would require *different* impact parameters. I'll write an answer that incorporates how not all latitudes are accessible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Orbital *refilling* ([as Musk stresses](https://youtu.be/3N7L8Xhkzqo?t=3287)) is critical to any deep space ambitions for Starship. In the latest (Feb. 2022) Starship update [Musk said so](https://youtu.be/3N7L8Xhkzqo?t=1491) (re: orbital refilling, emphasis added):

> This is going to be an important thing to demonstrate [...] Won't be in the near term for Starlink launches but it **will be necessary for Mars and the Moon.**

This can be confirmed looking at approximate Starship specs. [Starship's LEO payload is ~100+t](http://web.archive.org/web/20211228131013/https://www.spacex.com/media/starship_users_guide_v1.pdf) and Musk raised the possibility of 150 t in the Feb. 2022 update. Even if this payload was all propellant there is [not enough $\Delta V$ to even reach the Moon](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/58005/40257):

- [120t dry mass](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/54345/40257) + 100t of "payload propellant" + [380s $I_{sp}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Raptor) $\to$ $\Delta V$ = ~$2260m/s$
- [120t dry mass](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/54345/40257) +  150t of "payload propellant" + [380s $I_{sp}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Raptor) $\to$ $\Delta V$ = ~$3020m/s$

**Thus an unrefilled Starship cannot escape Earth.**

---

Most (if not all?) *sole in-situ atmospheric & beyond* missions (i.e., no orbiter component) directly enter the planet's atmosphere from their interplanetary trajectory (makes sense: why bring propellant to slow down where "air" will suffice?). This turns out to be rather difficult to do for a Venus polar mission, not entirely due to dynamics, but geometry.

A typical low energy transfer window to Venus from Earth looks like this in a porkchop plot:

[image: Venus 2025-2026 window]
(Personal work, click to enlarge)

The spoiler parameter is the Spacecraft-Venus-Earth angle on the right. At low angles the arrival $v_{\infty}$ vector is basically parallel with the Venus-Earth line. It is important to not forget that Venus has significant mass and will *deflect the spacecraft's hyperbolic trajectory* prior to atmospheric interface and subsequent landing:

[image: low angle example]
(Personal work)

The above figure is a 3D (unfortunately only for me) visualization of an example low energy (L: 7-Jun-2026, A: 29-Nov-2026, C3=15.9 km^2/s^2, $V_{entry}$=10.8 km/s), low angle (2.34°) trajectory. The black solid lines are 12 individual hyperbolic trajectories that represent **constant [hyperbolic impact parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_trajectory#Impact_parameter_and_the_distance_of_closest_approach) [B-plane](https://ai-solutions.com/_freeflyeruniversityguide/the_b_plane.htm) coordinates** (a circle in a B-plane plot). The magenta dots represent the atmospheric interface point (250 km) and the green points represent 0 altitude (no atmospheric/entry effects considered, so a real trajectory would likely have a shorter in-atmosphere down track distance). The dotted black line is the $v_{\infty}$ vector. The red, green, and blue lines show the J2000 ecliptic XYZ (respectively) reference frame. The yellow line is pointing towards the Sun and the light blue line is pointing towards the Earth. Note that the angle between the dashed black line and the light blue Earth line is the Spacecraft-Venus-Earth angle.

**There's a lot going on in this figure, and it's unfortunately only 2D for viewers, *but understanding it is critical.***

The above example uses an impact parameter value that puts the periapsis of the hyperbolic trajectory at Venus' surface ($||\vec{B}||=18,432 km$, entry flight path angle (EFPA) of -12.2°, [FWIW](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for-what-its-worth)). Also note that this visualization/sim *ignores* the orientation/pointing of Venus' pole, though its [tilt and inclination are both low enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus) to not play that important of a role here (maybe ~5° error between +Z, blue, and Venus' north pole).

Note how **not all latitudes are accessible for landing** despite spanning all of the ["theta" angles in the B-plane](https://ai-solutions.com/_freeflyeruniversityguide/the_b_plane.htm). The green dots begin to coalesce in a ring of accessible landing points. The spread of the accessible surface points depends on the arrival energy ($v_{\infty}$) and impact parameter. A lower arrival energy means more deflection and thus *more latitude locking*.

If you view the above figure along the Earth-Venus line (i.e., from Earth), you'll see this:

[image: low angle from Earth]
(Personal work)

Notably you *don't* see any magenta or green dots meaning **there is no Earth visibility of the critical EDL events.** There are solutions for this (i.e., [MarCO-A,B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Cube_One) or a relay satellite), but it is another complexity to consider. Also consider that because [Venus rotates so slowly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus#:%7E:text=A%20Venusian%20sidereal%20day%20thus%20lasts%20longer%20than%20a%20Venusian%20year%20(243%20versus%20224.7%20Earth%20days).%20Venus%27s%20equator%20rotates%20at%206.52%C2%A0km/h%20(4.05%C2%A0mph)%2C%20whereas%20Earth%27s%20rotates%20at%201%2C674.4%C2%A0km/h%20(1%2C040.4%C2%A0mph).%5B) those landing sites won't have direct line of site to Earth for ~months.

This is an extreme example, but it is very illustrative and noteworthy that *low arrival energy trajectories are associated with low Spacecraft-Venus-Earth angles*.

Higher arrival energies and oblique Spacecraft-Venus-Earth angles mitigate this, along with some declination angle for the arrival $v_{\infty}$ vector to "tilt" the ring of accessible surface points up or down towards a pole. Here is a promising looking example of this (using all 3 effects to its advantage):

[image: promising Earth view]
[image: promising oblique view]

(Personal work, Earth view left, L:5-Sept-2026, A:18-Feb-2027, C3=11.6 km^2/s^2, $V_{entry}$=12.1 km/s, S/C-Venus-Earth angle of 54.8°, click to enlarge)

This solves the *geometry* problem but introduces extreme *dynamics* problems for Starship. Table 1 from [Dutta et al.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241629284_Mission_sizing_and_trade_studies_for_low_ballistic_coefficient_entry_systems_to_Venus) and this figure from [Wercinski et al.](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20130001711) show the extreme nature of a Venus direct entry (click to enlarge):

[image: Table 1]
[image: Figure]

The above plot is for a *very different* vehicle design (45° sphere cone), but the trends are representative and the absolute values are probably also representative within an order of magnitude. Also note that the above trajectory has a considerably higher entry velocity than any listed in the table.

Note that depending on Starship's loading/configuration its [ballistic coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_coefficient#Satellites_and_reentry_vehicles), $\beta$, can range from a minimum of a few hundred to a maximum of a few thousand $\frac{kg}{m^2}$. Higher $\beta$ values necessitate steeper entries (larger EFPA) which lead to higher inertial loading and higher peak heating. I will emphasize that the **green contours represent intervals of *100's of g's* and the blue contours *1000's of $\frac{W}{cm^2}$!*** This is almost certainly outside of Starship's planned capabilities, and by no means easy to address.

- See [my answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/56021/40257) to [Starship reentry velocity on return from Mars: What are the options](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55533/40257) for Starship entry insights.

For completeness, [work has been done to explore very low stress Venus direct entries](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20130001711) (same source for above figure), but Starship as we know it is incapable of those low ballistic coefficients.

**For these reasons, and because [Starship has an enormous amount of $\Delta V$](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57572/40257) (when refilled), I think it makes sense to first insert into orbit around Venus before entry.**

A Starship entry from Venusian orbit is probably comfortably within the vehicle's capabilities. Summing the total $\Delta V$ from a 250 km LEO to a low, 300 km Venusian polar orbit (+ 100 m/s for deorbit) for that same 2025-2026 window looks like this:

[image: Total dV 2025-26 window]
(Personal work)

Interestingly, this construct shifts the window a few weeks earlier than the C3 constrained representation at the beginning. The minimum $\Delta V$ for this window is 7335 m/s and occurs in the less than ideal Type III/IV trajectories in the upper "porkchop" region. **It can be shown that the payload mass for a fully fueled Starship with 7335 m/s of $\Delta V$ is ~75 t** (using available specs):

$$\Delta V = 7335 = I_{sp} \cdot g_0 \cdot \ln(\frac{120t+m_{pay}+1200t}{120t+m_{pay}}) \to m_{pay}=75t$$

Where 120t and 1200t are the dry and [propellant masses of a full Starship](https://www.spacex.com/vehicles/starship/), respectively.

**References:**

1. Dutta, Soumyo & Smith, Brandon & Prabhu, Dinesh & Venkatapathy, Ethiraj. (2012). Mission sizing and trade studies for low ballistic coefficient entry systems to Venus. IEEE Aerospace Conference Proceedings. [10.1109/AERO.2012.6187002](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6187002/). [Free on ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241629284_Mission_sizing_and_trade_studies_for_low_ballistic_coefficient_entry_systems_to_Venus)
2. Wercinski et al. "Enabling Venus In-Situ Science - Deployable Entry System Technology, Adaptive Deployable Entry and Placement Technology (ADEPT): A Technology Development Project funded by Game Changing Development Program of the Space Technology Program," (2012) [NTRS ID: 20130001711](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20130001711)

Comment: For a payload mass of **75 t** at the surface, could Starship itself stay in orbit ?

Comment: @Cornelis No, that figure assumes Starship does the entry, descent, and landing.

Comment: @Cornelis if you open the imgur link in a new tab and remove the "m" at the end of the url it will show full size, this goes for all of the smaller images. The table and plot next to it are also available in their respective sources

Comment: @Cornelis like I said: ["I'm very confident that's the whole lander, but no proof"](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/58278/with-and-without-refueling-at-leo-how-much-more-than-the-landers-weight-of-the/58298?noredirect=1#comment193159_58278). Also like I said: ["that figure assumes Starship does the entry, descent, and landing"](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/58278/with-and-without-refueling-at-leo-how-much-more-than-the-landers-weight-of-the/58298?noredirect=1#comment193305_58298) so the...

Comment: @Cornelis ...75t payload + Starship reaches the surface with a terminal velocity of ~30 km/h

Comment: @Cornelis No, [$g_0$ is constant at 9.81](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation#:~:text=is%20standard%20gravity.) regardless of where the spacecraft is in the universe

Comment: Yes, I feel ashamed ! With the formula given by  @Mark Adler I calculated a delta-v of 6812 m/s, for  the normal "in the planets plane" case. That would be even better than the 6900 m/s that Elon Musk twittered.